# SUMPRODUCT reference to another tab

Tags: excel

I am currently using this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(YEAR(E2:E81)=2018))` However i want to run this formula on a summary tab and the data will be on another sheet called "BRIDGE". I tried `=SUMPRODUCT(BRIDGE!1*(YEAR(E2:E81)=2018))` but I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting the sheet reference as you have, put it prior to the range instead.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(YEAR(BRIDGE!E2:E81)=2018))
```